# Convert enum from one module to another module with same enum name

Tags: swift

My project is using framework and both framework and project are using same enum values. But when I passing param from Main app to module controller I'm getting that they are not same so way to do it is to convert it. I create extension:

```
extension Result {
    init(_ data: Messaging.MessagingResult) {
        switch data {
            case .authenticationFailed:     self = .authenticationFailed
            case .connectionError:          self = .connectionError
        }
    }
}
```

and now I have to create function which will take project enum back to module enums

```
 let adaptedConsume = transform(from: self.consume)
```

Is this right approach and how transform function should look like

Comment: Are you getting an error? This seems to do what you describe.

Comment: I need body code of transform function which will change module.enum to module1.enum

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if I understood your question, but supposing that what you want to do is to map the values of one enum to another, you can just use `typealias` to do that.

Swift makes it a lot to map types from Objective C to Swift.

Something like `typealias Result = Messaging.MessagingResult` should work.

You can know more about typealis from [Swift Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID361).

Comment: I had a similar issue, packages `A` and `B` had basically the same types and I never had `typealias` in mind to solve this. Thanks a lot!